# Azure Pipelines iOS provisioning profile installed but cannot be found

Tags: ios, xamarin, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My build pipeline for a Xamarin App fails with `The specified iOS provisioning profile '<GUID>' could not be found.`. Although the developer certificate and the provisioning profile are installed in previous build tasks.

Due to requirements of our customer the build script must also work on their infrastructure, so I am forced to do call `make` from the script task.

This is how I install the certificate and profile.

```yaml
  - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    inputs:
      certSecureFile: 'DeveloperCertificate'
      certPwd: '$(DeveloperCertificatePassword)'
      keychain: 'temp'  

  - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    inputs:
      provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
      provProfileSecureFile: 'ProvisioningProfile'
```

and my msbuild call in the Makefile:

```
msbuild -p :CodesignKey="$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)" -p:CodesignProvision="$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)" -p:Configuration=Release -p:Platform=IPhone -p:BuildIpa=true
```

The `APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY` and `APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID` are both correctly assigned by the corresponding Install tasks.

I am stuck. Are there any additional steps required to get access to the installed certificate and provisioning profile from the Script Task?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not.